# how to download files from google drive via command line

Tags: download, command

I would need to download files or folders from my google drive, via command line.
Thought to a script, a batch file, windows platform.

Seen that I could use gdrive app but I have some troubles with syntax.

I tried:

```
gdrive-windows-x64.exe download -r --path "G:\My Drive\myfolder"
```

but it gets me error as "invalid arguments"

Also I'm interested to a way to zip the content of a folder upon my google drive...again via command line

someone can help me?

thanks a lot
marco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have available a Command-line utility for working with Google Drive  in github here:

https://github.com/google/skicka

Examples:

```
skicka download /folder1 ~/folder2
```

The contents of your ~/folder2 directory will match the contents of ~/folder1.

For download to local:

```
skicka download /local ~/remote
```

Comment: thank you very much! may you send me also an example of syntax for downloading a folder A upon gdrive to a folder B on my local pc?

Comment: See the examples in my edited answer.  I hope this helps!, if so please mark it as the answer. Thanks so much!!!

Comment: ok, sure, thanks. So the first argument is the local path and the second is the remote path?

Comment: thank you J_P! quite arrived at the end but still some troubles... skicka ends with error...it returns me some error like "skicka: my main folder\my sub folder\my file: skipping download of duplicate file on Drive"... also for files/folders not included in my download...and moreover that fils are not duplicated...my command is: skicka download "myfolder\mysubfolder1" "c:\temp\test"

Comment: could it be some blank space, special or particular characters in the name or path?

Comment: the space at the end is surely a problem...but i cannot delete or revise all the names...they are million...

Comment: The space could be a problem, as it's on github, you could take a look to the code, or message some of the great contributors of the project to find a solution to these issues you are experiencing  (I'm not one of them unfortunately, and not involved in skicka development...)

Comment: thank you J_P! i will send a message to them. how can i mark this post  as answered?

Comment: take a look to this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers   Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

[Drive](https://github.com/odeke-em/drive) is an option.

- Create a new folder and do the [Initializing](https://github.com/odeke-em/drive#initializing) setting up;
- Create the sub folder mirroring the remote folder structure;
- Cd to the sub folder and run `$ drive pull`

[Click here](https://github.com/odeke-em/drive#pulling) for more pulling documentation.

Answer (score 1):

[gdrive](https://github.com/prasmussen/gdrive) is an option written in GoLang. This does require connecting a Google account.  This command downloads a Google Drive directory:

```
gdrive download --recursive DRIVEID
```